# Error when compiling C++ program: "error: cast from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ loses precision"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get 2 errors when trying to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int i;
char myCharArray[51] = "This string right here contains exactly 50 chars.";
double myDoubleArray[4] = {100, 101, 102, 103}; 

char *cp, *cbp;
double *dp, *dbp;
dp = &myDoubleArray[0];
dbp = myDoubleArray;
cp = &myCharArray[0];
cbp = myCharArray;

while ((cp-cbp) < sizeof(myCharArray)) {cp++; dp++; }

cout << "Without cast: " << (dp-dbp) << endl;
cout << " Cast 1: " << ((int *) dp-(int *) dbp) << endl;
cout << " Cast 2: " << ((int) dp-(int) dbp) << endl;
}
```

The errors I get are:

error: cast from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

error: cast from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

g++ won't let me compile the program. I'm asking what I could change to make it compile.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SamIam _"those look more like warnings"_ Well, though stating pretty clear, what could go wrong with the cast.

Comment: @SamIam g++ won't compile it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cast from ‘double*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
```

is as simple as it could be read: The number of bits to store in an int is less then the number of bits which are stored in a pointer on your platform. Normally it helps to make the `int` to an `unsigned int`, because on most platforms a pointer can be stored in an unsigned int type. A unsigned int has one more bit for the value because there is no need to decide between positive and negative. And pointers are always positive.

And even better is to use the  types for such things to make your code more portable. Have a look for `uintptr_t`

Comment: On 64-bit Linux platforms, pointers are 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits. I know of no system where casting from `double*` to `int` would lose precision and casting from `double*` to `unsigned int` would not; the conversion will *probably* just copy or reinterpret the low-order 32 bits either way. "*And pointers are always positive.*" -- Incorrect. In C++ (as in C) pointers are no sign, since they aren't numbers. There could well be systems where converting a pointer to a signed integer (of the proper size) make more sense than converting it to an unsigned integer, given the low-level semantics.

Comment: And casting to `uintptr_t` will avoid the compiler error, but it won't cause the code to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your `"Without cast"` line performs pointer subtraction, which yields the difference (in units of the size of the pointed-to type) between two pointers. If the two pointers point to elements of the same array, or just past the end of it, then the difference is the number of array elements between them. The result is of the signed integer type `ptrdiff_t`.

That's a perfectly sensible thing to do.

Your second line (`"Cast 1:"`) converts the pointers (which are of type `double*`) to `int*` before the subtraction. That in effect *pretends* that the pointers are pointing to elements of an array of `int`, and determines the number of elements between the `int` objects to which they point. It's not at all clear why you'd want to do that.

Your third line (`"Cast 2:"`) converts both pointer values to `int` before subtracting them. If `int` is not big enough to hold the converted pointer value, then the result may be nonsense. If it is, then *on most systems* it will probably yield the distinct between the two pointed-to objects in bytes. But I've worked on systems (Cray T90) where the byte offset of a pointer is stored in the high-order 3 bits of the pointer value. On such a system your code would *probably* yield the distance between the pointed-to objects in words. Or it might yield complete nonsense. In any case, the behavior is undefined.

The problem with the conversion from `double*` to `int` isn't just that it loses precision (which is what your compiler happened to complain about). It's that the result of the conversion doesn't necessarily mean anything.

The easiest, and probably the best, way to get your code to compile is to delete the second and third lines.

If you want a solution other than that, you'll have to explain what you're trying to do. Converting the pointer values to `uintptr_t` will probably avoid the error message, but it won't cause what you're doing to make sense.